# Compiling C code errors LNK2005 and LNK1169 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have problem when compiling the code that calculate the total sum of positive integer. What puzzled me is I managed to compile and run the code successfully on Online C Compiler (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) but get LNK2005 and LNK1169 error on VS2017. How to fix it?

```
//Calculate total sum of positive integer.

#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int n);

int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("Enter positive value of integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nTotal value for %d is = %d\n", n, sum(n));
    return (0);
}

int sum(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    else return (n*(n+1)/2);
}
```

By the way, kindly ignore the scanf warning on VS2017, I will change it back to scanf_s later.

Comment: What do the errors say?

Comment: @immibis LNK2005: _main already defined in Source.obj and LNK1169: Multiply defined symbols found.

By following the webpage link for each errors, LNK1169 yield nothing but LNK2005 told me that there might be a problem on how I use recursion in C. Although I didn't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Check if there is more than one source file that contains main function

Comment: Did you build for a console application?

Comment: I do not see any recursion in the shown code. Have you forgotten to show something?

Comment: The code you posted compiles and links for me in Visual Studio 2017.  Are you sure the code above reproduces your problem?  See [mcve] for more hints.

Comment: @PeMaCN Thank you, ohh god I feel so embarrassed doing simple mistake like that. I will update the solution below.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, but as stated by PeMaCN, my actual problem is putting 2 source code in one solution. The problem already solved.

Comment: @FrankBoyne My mistake lie on putting 2 source code in one vs solution. As stated by PcMaCN I just need to delete the extra code and it will compile successfully. I'm actually quite new in vs, before that I mainly use gcc thus my bad habit might carry on vs.

Comment: Also, `#Calculate total sum of positive integer` - this is not allowed. Comments are supposed to be written `//` or `/* ... */` syntax. What you have there is an invalid preprocessing directive.

Comment: @AnT Edited, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common error that occurs if you have more than one source file that contains main function.

Comment: The first sentence could be removed without changing the validity of the answer. I would be inclined to do so, as comments might be deleted in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occured because there are 2 source files inside my VS2017 solution. Removing one will allow the program to compile successfully.

Comment: You should give credit to the one who gave you the hint. @PeMaCN might be pleased or might want to make his own answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch My bad. Already mark his answer as the correct one.

Comment: Still it was viable as PeMaCN has not posted it yet and might never have who could know this at that moment.

Comment: @KamiKaze Yes, making their own answer is totally OK for an OP, even if it is based on a comment by somebody else. Just saying so is kind of expected and mabye pinging the person who helped.

Comment: @Yunnosch True and this comment was just to enforce that OP might not think that he/she did the wrong thing here.